# ZfcUser: How do I do my own authentication?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am facing the problem that I have to implement a way to authenticate a user against a SecurityService and, after that, get some data about him out of my database.

I want to use the ZfcUser Plugin and I am confused by Adapters, AdapterChains and AuthServices. 
I really would appreciate some clarification about those classes and when to use them and in particular which one will be the type of class I have to use to communicate with my SecurityService.

Comment: I can't give you a concrete example myself, but please look at this pullrequest! This is implementing an LDAP Authentication and basically it covers every single topic you'd need to cover, too. https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/pull/218

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your reply.

That pull request did not help too much, but basically it does what I now did. To get a new AuthAdapter you can orientate yourself at the code of the Db-AuthAdapter. Your logic for authenticating needs to be placed in your authenticate() method obviously :)